# Emails sent to Additional Email Addresses on No Access Deliverability

Tags: email, email-alert, approval-process, deliverability

I have set Email Deliverability to "No Access" to prevent users from receiving any emails from Salesforce as we are testing before going live.  This is in production.  We have approval processes email alerts.

No emails sent out as expected EXCEPT the Approval Process's email alert to the "Additional To Email Addresses" (not the To) only.  It didn't go to the To user.

Why the Additional To?

Answer (score 0):

Verify, `Receive Approval Request Email` of that user record, user will receive emails based on this correct selection other than `Never`.

[image: Receive Approval Request Email]

Comment: But shouldn't the Deliverability email settings override this as deliverability is disabling *any* emails from system level?